# Getting level from factor column in data frame based on numeric range

Tags: r, discretization, bnlearn

I'm trying to get the level of a number based on where it is in the range of values of a factor column in a dataframe.

```
library(bnlearn)

i <- iris
idata4 <- i[,c(1:4)] #only first four columns, which are continuous
diris <- discretize(idata4, method = "hartemink", breaks = 8, ibreaks = 9, idisc = "quantile")
levels(diris$Sepal.Length)
> [1] "[4.3,4.9]"  "(4.9,5.1]"  "(5.1,5.4]"  "(5.4,5.7]"  "(5.7,5.98]" "(5.98,6.3]" "(6.3,6.84]" "(6.84,7.9]"
```

I'm trying to get the factor label based on a new value. Given a value, 5.5, is there a way to get the label?

```
"(5.4,5.7]"
```

so I can assign it to a variable? Something like this?

```
newVariable <- function(5.5, diris$Sepal.Length)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `bnlearn`, but can you get what the breaks are? Then you can supply that vector of breaks to `cut`, calling `cut` on a new vector of values with those breaks

Comment: Could the levels be parsed to something `cut` can work with?

Comment: maybe something at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31702464/manipulation-on-levels-produced-by-cut-r-function will help parse the levels